# WPF: Setting the Width (and Height) as a Percentage Value

Tags: wpf, xaml, resize

Say I want a `TextBlock` to have its `Width` equal to it's Parent container's `Width` (ie,  stretch from side to side) or a percentage of it's Parent Container `Width`, how can I accomplish this in `XAML` without specifying absolute values?

I want to do this so that if the Parent Container container is later on expanded (its' `Width` increased), its' Child Elements will also be expanded automatically.  (basically, like in HTML and CSS)

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604952/wpf-allow-textbox-to-be-resized-but-not-to-grow-on-user-input).

Comment: Use cwap's answer and include the tb in a grid setting it's alignment to stretch.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The way to stretch it to the same size as the parent container is to use the attribute:

```
 <Textbox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ...
```

That will make the Textbox element stretch horizontally and fill all the parent space horizontally (actually it depends on the parent panel you're using but should work for most cases).

Percentages can only be used with grid cell values so another option is to create a grid and put your textbox in one of the cells with the appropriate percentage.

Answer (score 262):

You can put the textboxes inside a grid to do percentage values on the rows or columns of the grid and let the textboxes auto-fill to their parent cells (as they will by default). Example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

This will make #1 2/5 of the width, and #2 3/5.

Comment: I already tried that, but I'm getting this error: '2*' string cannot be converted to Length.'

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot, thanks!
I tried to figure out what the * does for years, you explained it so short and good.

Comment: :-) ,... the * is called "star"

Comment: Actually, *(Asterisk) is little star ;) http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=asterisk

Comment: This does not work, even if the TextBox is in a Grid. The width can be set to a Double, Qualified Double (A double value followed by px, in, cm or pt) or Auto. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.width.aspx

Comment: Yes.. This is actually a very poor reply, but based on all the upvotes, I suppose it helped someone (was a long time ago), which is why I haven't deleted it.

Comment: Now that we're at the end of '17, 2* 3* is absolutely valid. Even the Visual Studio GUI provides fields to specify such values.

Comment: Just wanted to offer another confirmation that this does work with newer xaml versions

Answer (score 67):

Typically, you'd use a built-in layout control appropriate for your scenario (e.g. use a grid as a parent if you want scaling relative to the parent).  If you want to do it with an arbitrary parent element, you can create a ValueConverter do it, but it probably won't be quite as clean as you'd like.  However, if you absolutely need it, you could do something like this:

```cs
public class PercentageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, 
        Type targetType, 
        object parameter, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToDouble(value) * 
               System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, 
        Type targetType, 
        object parameter, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Which can be used like this, to get a child textbox 10% of the width of its parent canvas:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:PercentageConverter x:Key="PercentageConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello"
                   Background="Red" 
                   Width="{Binding 
                       Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, 
                       ElementName=canvas, 
                       Path=ActualWidth, 
                       ConverterParameter=0.1}"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: This is really cool,  how can I do it in code (set the width of the textbox)?

Comment: You should consider adding `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to the double conversion because the `parameter` is regarded as `string` and in cultures with different `decimal separator` it will not work as expected.

Comment: While searching this topic, I did come across this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59934565/7108481 which basically does the same but has gone a step further and implemented an attached property.

Answer (score 41):

For anybody who is getting an error like : **'2*' string cannot be converted to Length.**

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" /><!--This will make any control in this column of grid take 2/5 of total width-->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" /><!--This will make any control in this column of grid take 3/5 of total width-->
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="30" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">Your text block a:</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">Your text block b:</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why not `<RowDefinition Height="auto" />`?

Comment: "auto" takes only as much space as the control needs

Comment: Thank you so much, this should be the top answer.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

IValueConverter implementation can be used. Converter class which takes inheritance from IValueConverter takes some parameters like `value` (percentage) and `parameter` (parent's width) and returns desired width value. In XAML file, component's width is set with the desired value:

```cs
public class SizePercentageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter == null)
            return 0.7 * value.ToDouble();

        string[] split = parameter.ToString().Split('.');
        double parameterDouble = split[0].ToDouble() + split[1].ToDouble() / (Math.Pow(10, split[1].Length));
        return value.ToDouble() * parameterDouble;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // Don't need to implement this
        return null;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <m:SizePercentageConverter x:Key="PercentageConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          Width="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Border}},Path=ActualWidth}"
          Height="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PercentageConverter}, ConverterParameter=0.6, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Border}},Path=ActualHeight}">
....
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 4):

I know it's not XAML, but I did the same thing with SizeChanged event of the textbox:

```cs
private void TextBlock_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
   TextBlock textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
   FrameworkElement element = textBlock.Parent as FrameworkElement;
   textBlock.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, (element.ActualWidth / 100) * 20, 0);
}
```

The textbox appears to be 80% size of its parent (well right side margin is 20%) and stretches when needed.

Answer (score 4):

I use two methods for relative sizing. I have a class called `Relative` with three attached properties `To`, `WidthPercent` and `HeightPercent` which is useful if I want an element to be a relative size of an element anywhere in the visual tree and feels less hacky than the converter approach - although use what works for you, that you're happy with.

The other approach is rather more cunning. Add a `ViewBox` where you want relative sizes inside, then inside that, add a `Grid` at width 100. Then if you add a `TextBlock` with width 10 inside that, it is obviously 10% of 100.

The `ViewBox` will scale the `Grid` according to whatever space it has been given, so if its the only thing on the page, then the `Grid` will be scaled out full width and effectively, your `TextBlock` is scaled to 10% of the page.

If you don't set a height on the `Grid` then it will shrink to fit its content, so it'll all be relatively sized. You'll have to ensure that the content doesn't get too tall, i.e. starts changing the aspect ratio of the space given to the `ViewBox` else it will start scaling the height as well. You can probably work around this with a `Stretch` of `UniformToFill`.