# Give Windows Form control a percentage width/height

Tags: .net, winforms

Kind of new to Windows Form development, but well-experienced in web development. Is there a way to assign a percentage width/height to a Windows Form control so that it expands/shrinks as the user resizes the window? It would be possible to write code to alter the width/height of the control as the window resizes, but I'm hoping there's a better way like in HTML/CSS. Is there?

Comment: you can anchor controls, so they will resize automatically...not sure if that's enough for your requirements though - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx

Comment: Try using the TableLayoutPanel for that.

Comment: @NDJ The anchor property actually worked for my purposes (I wanted width/height 100% on a control) but isn't a complete answer to the question since something like 90% width wouldn't be possible through just anchoring.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but I strongly recommend WPF (or any other XAML-based framework) instead of winforms, particularily if you come from a Web development background. the XAML paradigm is much closer to the Web paradigm than the traditional winforms procedural approach. Plus, winforms is a really old technology and you should not lose your time in learning it if you don't really need it. winforms is only recommended to maintain legacy applications, but is no longer used for any new projects.

Comment: in WPF, [you can achieve percentual sizes using a simple `Grid`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12463781/643085).

Comment: Glad anchoring helped a bit in this instance - I have to agree with @HighCore - WPF is the way forward if you can

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In a word, no. You can easily do it programmatically in the Parent control resize event though. For example:

```
    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Width = Convert.ToInt32(this.Width * 0.9);
        dataGridView1.Height = Convert.ToInt32(this.Height * 0.9);
    }
```

But if you can, use WPF as mentioned in the comments above.