# How can I make a control take 80% of the parent's height

Tags: c#, winforms

I know you can dock an item to cover the bottom, top, left, right, or all of the form. But I want to have a datagridview cover 80% of the height of the forum and all of the width and cannot figure out how to do that.

Comment: Are you using winforms or WPF?

Comment: I am using windows forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the docking (e.g. `Top` or `Bottom`) to setup the width part of your problem, however, to synchronize the height you'll need to programmatically calculate it (and keep it synced).

There's an example here that sets the width so that idea will apply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18384344/33969. You'll want to call that function on form load, but also as an event handler for the [Form.Resize event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `TableLayoutPanel` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to accomplish this, and can be done entirely in the designer.

Add a `TableLayoutPanel` and have it fill you entire form. Then, create 2 rows in the panel and give the first row a percentage value of 80% for height (Your options are percentage, pixels, and auto-fill). Finally, move your `DataGridView` into the first row and dock it to the entire row.