# WPF Percentage Converter

Tags: wpf

I did exactly what was suggested by kvb in

[WPF: Setting the Width (and Height) as a Percentage Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717299/wpf-setting-the-width-and-height-as-a-percentage-value)

and used his PercentageConverter. However, in design view, the elements appear with the correct percentage. When I run the application, the components stretch beyond the full width of the window. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: don't you think it'll be hard to say without more info?

Comment: This is the converter:

Comment: The converter is the same of the question mentioned, and fragmant of the XAML is:

...

    <StackPanel>
        <WrapPanel>
            <Grid Width="{Binding Converter={StaticResource percentageConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type WrapPanel}}, Path=ActualWidth, ConverterParameter=0.2}" Height="auto">
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">Button 1.1</Button>
            </Grid>
        </WrapPanel>
    </StackPanel>

Comment: In design view, the button width is 20% of the window (StackPanel stretches to the window's width). But when I run the application, the button appears wider than the the window's width.