# Dynamic Rectangle Height

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have to fill my window with three adjustable `Rectangles` like:

[image]

```
<Grid x:Name="FileDragAndDrop" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="Aqua">
     <Rectangle Fill="Beige" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="110" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
     <Rectangle Fill="Aquamarine" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="110" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
     <Rectangle Fill="BlanchedAlmond" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="110" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</Grid>
```

But the above code does this:

[image]

I tried `Height="2*"` ([following the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717299/wpf-setting-the-width-and-height-as-a-percentage-value/717314#717314)) but it gives error

> '2*' string cannot be converted to length

How can I resolve this error and make their height dynamic? Is it possible with the `xaml` or will I have to do it in `C#`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you cannot put the rectangles into rows of the main grid, you can use a nested Grid and `Grid.RowSpan` to cover the nested Grid over the whole main grid.

```
<Grid x:Name="FileDragAndDrop" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="Aqua">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <!-- suppose you have 3 RowDefinitions here -->
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid Grid.RowSpan="3">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition MinHeight="110"/>
         <RowDefinition MinHeight="110"/>
         <RowDefinition MinHeight="110"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions/>
     <Rectangle Fill="Beige" Stroke="Black"/>
     <Rectangle Fill="Aquamarine" Stroke="Black" Grid.Row="1"/>
     <Rectangle Fill="BlanchedAlmond" Stroke="Black" Grid.Row="2"/>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Well ! there are already too many rows. Isn't there any other way around?

Comment: @Shaharyar so you want to let the 3 rects cover the whole grid anyway?

Comment: Yes. But they should be equal

Comment: @Shaharyar you can use `Grid.RowSpan` however the number of RowDefinition should be defined.

Comment: @Shaharyar see my update, we can use nested Grids. We use Grid here because it supports auto scaling the rows' height. Without that feature I think we have to use some code behind.

Comment: Never thought about `Nested Grid`. Its perfect now